# Can a Nordic Semiconductor nRF24L01+ be powered by 5V?

Tags: power, nrf24l01

When I look at the [nRF24L01+ datasheet](https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/content/download/2726/34069/file/nRF24L01P_Product_Specification_1_0.pdf), I'm confused by two apparently conflicting details.

- "1.9 to 3.6V supply range" (page 1, Key Features)
- 5.25V maximum input voltage Vi (page 12, "absolute maximum ratings")

So, two parts of my question:

- practically, can I power this chip from a regulated Vcc of 5V?
- what is the difference of "supply range" and "maximum input voltage" ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> practically, can I power this chip from a regulated Vcc of 5V?

No. The chip can take a maximum of 3.6V as its supply. And since its supply current is so low (<15mA) you can use one of those SOT-23 voltage regulators, so no reason not to.

> what is the difference of "supply range" and "maximum input voltage" ?

You *must* keep its supply voltage within its supply voltage range. You *can* apply a higher voltage at its digital inputs, i.e. connect a 5V CMOS output to one of the chip's inputs directly.

Comment: Thanks!  So to make sure I understand: "supply range" typically refers to the power input, and "maximum input voltage" typically refers to the digital lines?

Comment: Digital inputs, yes. Digital outputs may have their own limits.